# Django Rest Framework Restricting Views

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I am building a website that will host multiple apps. Some apps can only be accessed by certain groups from a LDAP backend. To achieve this on a pure Django stack, I used

```
user_has_perm
@user_passes_test()
```

so that certain views can only be accessed by users who has permission to add items (I give the permission to add items to certain groups, they are automatically placed into a group from the LDAP)

However, I am now migrating to a React + Django stack. How can I achieve a similar effect, where you can only access some apps if you are in the correct LDAP group.
Note - I have a single react app frontend that that uses routers to get to different component(apps)

Answer (score 0):

if you have hybrid architecture
the easiest solution is to do the same thing but with view for your react app

```
user_has_perm
@user_passes_test()
*view_that_renders_template_with_react*
```

if you have many pages and different pages with react router you can add an additional check if user is permitted to get to this page, you can add this information to the user or make request, if no do something, redirect or throw an Error like Error 403, also you can use native django-rest-framework permissions and check it during the requests, and do something if user has no permission. If you are not using react router, but you also have hybrid architecture (you connect react via django templates/static) , you can make many identical views, check for different things then define urls for them in django urls,
I'm not able to provide more clear explanation and attach code, because there is so much ways to build such app and each requires individual solution, so I just explained possible solutions, which to use and how, depends on your implementation and architechture you've chosen